# Customize minitest messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Is there a way to customize test reports. Currently I am getting this line at the end of each test:

```
3 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I want to include test file name to this line.

Comment: You want to customize a reporter, checkout http://chriskottom.com/blog/2014/06/dress-up-your-minitest-output/ and https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#adding-custom-reporters. This is also for each test run, not each individual test. If you want to see other meta information for each file as the test suite runs you would have to get pretty custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minitest has a verbose option that will show the test name and execution time for each test that's run.  How you pass the `-v` flag to Minitest will vary depending on how you're running your tests.  See http://chriskottom.com/blog/2014/12/command-line-flags-for-minitest-in-the-raw/ for a sample of verbose output.

Another option would be using minitest-reporters with the SpecReporter by adding it to your Gemfile and putting this in your test helper:

```
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new
```

See https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters for more info.